# Auto-incremental not working when multi-user saving at same time

Tags: php, magento

This is a little hard to explain.

I have a system (LAMP project), there's one feature that if user save a product, the system will automatically generate a number for it.

For example, the current biggest number in the system is abc-112. So if I create a new product and save it, I will get the number abc-113 automatically saved as an attibute of this new product.(a function will find the biggest number and plus 1 on it and return)

Now my problem is, if there're more than 1 user click saving product at same time in the system,  all the new products will get abc-113 but not abc-113 / abc-114 / abc-115 and so on.

Anyone got some idea of how to solve this ? Many THX !

EDIT:

The generation code is actually much more complicated than I wrote above, I was thought it's not very important to explain, but seems many people thought I can use DB-autoincrement index to instead of this, but sorry I can't, the calculation logic cannot be changed, for example a new product, the value can be abc-112 or abc-1502 or abc-2293, it's based on the product's category and category's parent category and product type, it's not just 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...

But anyway thx for the "DB" suggestions

EDIT#2:

Seems nobody can understand, ok I already solved it by making a lock, sorry for my bad English. Thx all the same!

Comment: what database you are using?

Comment: YCS answer is the solution to your problem.  I' just going to nag you not to use alphanumeric identifiers - they are slow to search and add nothing to your app.  Humans won't be reading this data now, will they...

Comment: You can create a composite primary key based in a prefix (your "abc-" and an autoincrement field with some of MySQL's database engines, which would be Acidic: what database engine are you using?

Comment: I cannot use DB to get this number, is a number which works must in this way, and the generation is much more complicated than I described, it depends on many calculations.

Comment: Which means it could be abc-112 or abc-1502, is not just 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: Then you want to insert a record with the new number and a unique key constraint as soon as possible, and if 2 users try to create at the same time the second will get a duplicate key error thrown and have to try getting another new number by your convoluted logic

Answer (score 4):

The only your problem is that **you aren't using autoincrement feature.**

So, get rid of this function to find the biggest number and plus 1 and **let database increment it**, as it was designed for.

Problem solved.

Comment: I cannot use DB to get this number, is a number which works must in this way, and the generation is much more complicated then I described, it depends on many calculations.

Comment: First insert to get an autoincrement, then get it, then calculate your super-intricately-complex identifier, then update